# Git does not prompt for ssh key password

Tags: ssh, git

I have an ssh key which is password protected.  When I attempt to SSH into a remote computer (ssh user@example.com), I get a little dialog which prompts me for the password.  Once I have provided the password, it is cached and I dont have to enter it again until I restart my computer.

I use the same ssh key as the credentials for allowing me to push to a git repository.  However, unless the password for the ssh key is already cached, when I try to push to the git repo, I do NOT get prompted for the password, and instead get the message:

```
 % git remote show staging                                                                                                                                                            !10455
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I ssh into one of the remote boxes, and get prompted for the password, I can then push to the git repository.

Is this a bug, or a setup issue with git?

Comment: On which OS is this happening?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist MacOS Lion

Comment: try: `eval `ssh-agent -s`; ssh-add ~/.ssh/*_rsa` this work on git bash on windows maybe it will also work on MacOS too.